# Promise version of a "while" loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I've come to the realization that since promises in ECMAScript 6 allow for synchronous coding of asynchronous functions, for every promise-laden piece of code there's a synchronous corollary. For instance:

```
var data = processData(JSON.parse(readFile(getFileName())));
```

Is the same as:

```
var data = getFileName()
    .then(readFile)
    .then(JSON.parse)
    .then(processData);
```

Now for my current use-case I want to write code to pull data from a massive public API. The API is paginated, so in a purely synchronous world I would write something like the following:

```
var data = [];
var offset = 0;
var total = 10000; // For example - not actually how this would work
while( offset < total ) {
    data.concat(getDataFromAPI(offset));
    offset = data.length;
}
```

Now my question is, how would I do this with promises? I could write something like:

```
var data = [];
var offset = 0;
var total = 10000;
getDataFromAPI(offset)
    .then(function(newData){
        data.concat(newData);
        return getDataFromAPI(data.length);
    });
```

But at this point I'm forced to just chain infinite `.then`s -- there's no looping logic. I feel like something should be possible using recursion, but I have no idea how to do it.

I'm using [BluebirdJS](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) as my promise library, so I have access to all of their helper methods.

Comment: What about a recursive self-invoking anonymous function (eventually combined with Promises) instead? here is just an example: https://jsfiddle.net/f5ud8ytx/ . Replace the timeout with your own api call and use the .then of the promise returned from the api call to call the function again until end reaches 0 (current-- executes until end is higher than 0)

Comment: you can do this easily with `async-each`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I feel like something should be possible using recursion

Exactly. You can name the callback so you can reference it again. As long as the condition isn't met, return a promise from the callback. Otherwise return the final result:

```
getDataFromAPI(offset)
  .then(function next(newData){
    data.concat(newData);
    var newOffset = data.length;
    return newOffset < total ? getDataFromAPI(newOffset).then(next) : data;
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // final result
  });
```